# ge7Locations-7.x-1.13 does not show in the modules administration in Drupal 7.31

Tags: location

Installed getlocations-7.x-1.13 on the sites/all/libraries/
but it does not show in the modules or administration/configuration/services
what to do?  Thanks

Comment: Modules go in sites/all/modules, not in the libraries folder

Comment: you need to put it in modules folder.. sites/all/modules